# A proper way to ignore my file from version control in my case

Tags: git, github

My project is already in github. Now, I want to ignore a file which is already version controlled.

What I did was I added that file to `.gitignore`. I understand that for the already tracked file, only add it to `.gitignore` is not enough, so I also did:

```
git rm my_file
```

,

My goal is I would like `my_file` being ignored from version control, **but** still on hard disk so that my project can still run locally. But after I did `git rm my_file`, I am not able to run my project because the `my_file` is missing. I also run command `ls`, and the file is not there.

How can I ignore the `my_file` from version control **but** still have it in my local disk so that my project can still run locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After listing your file in `.gitignore` you can just commit and push. this should delete the file on github.
Try with:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "myFile gitignored"
git push
```

Notice that `git add --all` will add all your changed to the next commit!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Adding already tracked file to `.gitignore` doesn't remove it from anywhere, nor does it ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the file to another location, git rm the file, add it to .gitignore and push those changes. You can then copy the file back into your repo and it will be ignored and not in git.